# Reference of "eigenen" in a Kafka sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

The question is on *eigenen* as occurring in this excerpt from Kafka's Der Verschollene.

> Es gab allerdings auch einige, die um jeden Preis schlafen wollten – Karl gehörte meist zu ihnen – und die, statt den Kopf aufs Kissen zu legen, ihn mit dem Kissen bedeckten oder hineinwickelten; aber wie wollte **man** im Schlaf bleiben, wenn **der nächste Nachbar** in tiefer Nacht aufstand, um vor dem Dienst noch ein wenig in der Stadt dem Vergnügen nachzugehen, wenn er in dem am Kopfende des **eigenen** Bettes angebrachten Waschbecken laut und wassersprühend sich wusch, wenn er die Stiefel nicht nur polternd anzog, sondern stampfend sich besser in sie hineintreten wollte – fast alle hatten trotz amerikanischer Stiefelform zu enge Stiefel –, um dann schließlich, da ihm eine Kleinigkeit in seiner Ausstattung fehlte, das Kissen des Schlafenden zu heben, unter dem man, allerdings schon längst geweckt, nur darauf wartete, auf ihn loszufahren.

**Questions**

I want to read *eigenen* as a reference to *man*, the person trying to sleep, rather than to the neighbor who is up and about to go out for pleasure.  So the pleasure seeker is washing at the basin affixed to the sleeper's bed!

1. Does the text support that reading?
2. Does the text compel that reading?  Or can a reader choose to see the basin as attached to the pleasure seeker's bed at least as a matter of grammar and dictionary meaning?

**Background**

You might finding it interesting that the two English language translations had to make a choice.  (I want to see the Muirs as having got it "right.")

Willa and Edwin Muir:

> but how was **one** to go on sleeping if the **boy** in the next bed. . . washed his face with a clatter and much scattering of water at the wash-basin fixed at the head of **one's** own bed. . .

Mark Harman:

> but how could **you** go on sleeping when the **occupant** of the adjacent bed. . . washed himself noisily, splashed water in the basin affixed to the head of **his** bed, . . .

See also, by Bernard Lortholary:

> mais comment vouliez-**vous** continuer à dormir quant votre **voisin**. . . et qu'il s'ébrouait et se lavait à grande eau dans le lavabo placé just à **votre** chevet. . .

Comment: I find that it would be meaningless for me to "accept" one of the answers seeing that there is such a sharp difference of opinion.  I was hoping a consensus would emerge, or at least a dominant view (through up-voting); but so far each answer has a vote score of 1.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you are correct. There are only two persons, *man* (obviously Karl) and *der nächste Nachbar*, so the basin has to be at the front end of one of those two beds. If it would be that of the neighbor, the sentence would simply read *am Kopfende seines Bettes*. So *des eigenen* translates to *ones own* quite straightforward. This is not strictly compelling, but very likely.

I don't think, that basin is affixed to the sleepers bed, its just located there.

Comment: Steht aber da: "Am Kopfende angebracht."

Comment: @userunknown Siehe [hier](https://books.google.de/books?id=FfXZeW7DYsYC&lpg=PA45&ots=AT4nLWju2u&dq=am%20kopfende%20angebracht&hl=de&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q=am%20kopfende%20angebracht&f=false) Würdest du da auch sagen, dass die Lampen am Bett sind (stelle ich mir ziemlich unbequem vor) oder ist vielleicht doch nur die x-Koordinate damit gemeint?

Comment: Ich sage gerade nicht, dass sie nur am Bett sind, sondern sie sind dran angebracht - steht ja auch da. Wandlampen. Du weißt, was eine Wandlampe ist?

Answer (score 2):

Ob er sich am eigenen Kopf kratz oder im Becken des am eigenen Bett angebrachten Waschbeckens sich wäscht - gemeint ist sicher der Kopf oder das Becken des anderen.

Alles andere macht auch inhaltlich wenig her. Wenn an jedem Bett ein Waschbecken angebracht ist, dann wohl, damit man sich im eigenen Becken wäscht.

Comment: Es steht nicht da, dass an jedem Bett ein Waschbecken ist. Bei der einen Interpretation ist vielmehr anzunehmen, dass der Nachbar auf das Waschbecken am Kopfende von Karls Bett angewiesen ist.

Comment: a) Ja, es könnte auch sein, dass nur beim Nachbarn ein Waschbecken an dessen Bett angebracht ist. b) Aber an dessen eigenem Bett - nicht an Kafkas Bett, das wäre 'meinem'.

Answer (score 1):

In my optinion the reference to the persion is not clear from the sentence. Both translations are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The text doesn't make it clear but there is really no reason to assume it is the sleeper's bed.

What it really tells us that the basins are right in the room among the beds and not at a more remote place or in another room, which makes the noise of the splashing etc all the more irritant.